# How to call javascript in for loop code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript", "<script>alert('hello world');</script>");
    }
}
```

The alert only execute once, is that possible to execute the alert everytime in the iteration?

Comment: I think the script can only be registered once, but anyhow it will always run after the page is sent to the client (the button click event is already finished being on the server side)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes by changing it to, note the "myScript" + i, it changes the key om every iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript" + i, "<script>alert('hello world');</script>");
        }
```

Comment: @Wagas, what about doing it in update panel?it is not working in update panel

Comment: @DEN i beleive its the same except you `.RegisterStartupScript(`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx

Comment: for update panel you can use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(..)

Comment: @james Khoury, i found out it only start calling the javascript function after the iteration. Is that possible to call it while it is looping through?

Comment: for the example above, it will only call alert for 100 times after the iteration is completed. Is that possible call the javascript function immediately for each looping?

Comment: @DEN nope you can't achieve what you are looking for because the looping is done in code behind and it first compiled by the asp.net process which in turn generated the appropriate html and javascript and send output back to browser

Comment: @Wagas, so do you have any idea how to do it on what i want to achieve?

Comment: @DEN you want the server to post code to the client and receive a response 100 times?

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution and for that you have to change key at every loop
like:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript", "<script>alert('hello world');</script>");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript1", "<script>alert('hello world');</script>");
```