# Javascript function executed only once

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

What I am trying to achieve is :
when a file is downloaded from FTP server it should add 2% to bootstrap progress-bar.

C# code is ok and files get downloaded but the progress-bar is stuck at 2%.

HTML and Javascript is ok and working, but when called from code behind it's executed only once. i.e. bootstrap progress-bar moves only to 2%.

C#

```
int count=2;
using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
{
            ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("win10", "zzzz");

            for (int i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                if (directories[i].Contains("."))
                {

                    string path = "ftp://192.168.0.120/" + directories[i].ToString();
                    string trnsfrpth = @"E:\\ProjectLocalPath\" + directories[i].ToString();
                    ftpClient.DownloadFile(path, trnsfrpth);
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "lol", "javascript: updateProgress('" + count2 + "')", true);
                    count2 += 2;

                }



          }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div3" runat="server" class="progress progress-danger progress-striped progress progress_sm active" style="width: 425%;">
    <div id="e3" style="width: 0%;" class="bar" runat="server" role="progressbar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var _prevent;
    var percentage;
    function updateProgress(percentage) {
        _prevent = setInterval(function () {
            var $bar = $('.bar');
            if (percentage > 100) {
                percentage = 100;
                clearInterval(_prevent);
            }
            $bar.width(percentage);
            $bar.text(percentage + "%");
        },800);
    }
    window.clearInterval(_prevent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A startup script is uniquely identified by its key and its type. Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page. Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not create a duplicate of the script.

In others words, you need to create a different key for each of your loop's iteration (instead of just "lol").

Comment: Tried this " ' " + count2 + " ' " instead of " lol " still it didn't solve.

Comment: Take a look at Dalorzo's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872019/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-inside-while-loop-only-executed-after-breaki .

Comment: Can I update progress-bar by javascript while the C# function is being executed (calling javascript function in for loop, So that progress-bar 
value should be changed everytime) ?

Comment: No, @nApSt3r, you can't. Once you use ClientScript to register a javascript code, you need to finish your C# code and post back your page for the javascript to be executed. If you want such feature in your website, you'll have to use another approach.

Comment: To achieve that, Can I use update panel ? If not, Is there any other option ?