# calling javascript function multiple times from C# with different parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to call javascript function multiple times from C# but its executing only once.

Here's my C# code

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
                string data = " * ";
                string fromTable = " Decoration ";

                table = SqlHelper.LoadMyTableData(data, fromTable);

                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    string id = row["DecrationID"].ToString();
                    string name = row["DecorationName"].ToString();
                    string details = row["DecorationDetails"].ToString();
                    string servicesOffered = row["ServicesOffered"].ToString();
                    string imagePath = row["DecorationImagePath"].ToString();

                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Func('" + id + "')", true);
                    string scriptKey = "text" + id;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text5", "populateDecor('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + details + "','" + servicesOffered + "', '" + imagePath + "')", true);
                    i++;
                }
```

JavaScript Function

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function populateDecor(id, name, details, servicesOffered, imagePath) {

            alert(name);

            var text = "<div class=\"row ae__dec-details__item\">";
            text += " <div class=\"col-md-10\">";
            text += " <div class=\"media\">";
            text += "<div class=\"media-left\"> <a href=\"#\"> <img src=\"" + imagePath + "\" width=\"200\" alt=\"...\" class=\"media-object\" /></a> </div>";
            text += "<div class=\"media-body\">";
            text += "<h3 class=\"media-heading\">" + name + "</h3>";

            text += "<label>" + servicesOffered + "</label>";
            text += "<p>" + details + "</p>";
            text += "</div>  </div> </div>";
            text += "<div class=\"col-md-2 ae__dec-details__ca\">";
            text += "<a href=\"EventSketch-decorEdit.aspx?dp=" + id + "\" style=\"color:cornflowerblue; background-color:white; margin-bottom:5px\" class=\"ae__btn\">Edit</a>";
            text += "<a href=\"EventSketch-decor-confirmPackage.aspx?dp=" + id + "\" class=\"ae__btn\">Select</a>";
            text += "</div> </div>";

            $(".col-md-12").append(text);

        }
</script>
```

I have tried it with different script keys as well. but still only first record is appended in the div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass only 4 argument to register script like this `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "text5", "populateDecor('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + details + "','" + servicesOffered + "', '" + imagePath + "')", true);`

Comment: are you getting any js errors on browser console?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304692/how-to-call-javascript-in-for-loop-code-behind

Comment: @AmrElgarhy no i am not getting any error. The code is working fine but its only working once. The div is only appended by the arguments passed first.

Comment: @Kavin I have seen that post and I had already tried solution suggested there it wasn't working as i mentioned changing script keys not working either.

Comment: @Tabani okay. Did you fixed that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, It seems, you have passed the **key** param as hard coded (as **text5**) and missed the semicolon at end of calling function like @Bharatsing said his answer.

Replace the following any of the line in your code and try it. Hope it helps you!..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text"+ i, "populateDecor('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + details + "','" + servicesOffered + "', '" + imagePath + "');", true);
```

**OR**

**Note:** For this id should be unique for all the rows then only it will work correctly.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text"+ id, "populateDecor('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + details + "','" + servicesOffered + "', '" + imagePath + "');", true);
```

Comment: Thanks @kavin. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: You need to add `;` at end of calling finction.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
                string data = " * ";
                string fromTable = " Decoration ";

                table = SqlHelper.LoadMyTableData(data, fromTable);

                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    string id = row["DecrationID"].ToString();
                    string name = row["DecorationName"].ToString();
                    string details = row["DecorationDetails"].ToString();
                    string servicesOffered = row["ServicesOffered"].ToString();
                    string imagePath = row["DecorationImagePath"].ToString();

                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Func('" + id + "')", true);
                    string scriptKey = "text" + id;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text5", "populateDecor('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + details + "','" + servicesOffered + "', '" + imagePath + "');", true);
                    i++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggest easy resolve this problem.We recommend using literal for such operations. Before add literal element, add to bottom of page.  I added asp.net literal and javascript sample.

Default.aspx

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>

</form>
 <asp:Literal ID="ltrMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ltrMessage.Text="<script>alert('OK')</script>";
    }
```

Hope it helps.